# Balls into bins with capacities and constraints (DP)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

You have n balls and m bins with given capacities c_i. You are attempting to assign these balls to the bins to achieve a state where you have the maximum number of balls assigned. However, there is also a constraint that says that each ball  has a set of buckets to which it can be assigned.

I understand that a 2D DP solution could solve the problem without the constraint. However, does the constraint that each ball can only be added to a certain set of buckets add a 3rd dimension to the DP solution? I'm unsure on how to go forward because of the constraint.

Comment: You can model this as a max flow problem, and solve it with the [Edmonds-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds–Karp_algorithm). Or model it as a maximum bipartite matching problem, and solve it with the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft–Karp_algorithm). Either way, Karp is your friend :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking at this from the DP perspective instead of max flow. I figured it out now.

Comment: Any time, glad to hear that you've figured it out. Cheers!